# Can String hold greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE number of character

Tags: java, string

If I want to create a String object which contains x number of character, where x > Integer.MAX_VALUE, can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, 2GB+ string.  As noted below, can't be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java).

the field `count`, which indicates the string's size is an `int` - so you will get an overflow.

```
private final int count;
```

Comment: Also, without using the source, the `charAt()` method takes an `int` parameter, so one would have no way to access the characters beyond this size.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: True. I just find it a good habit to look at the source when I have these kind of questions, wanted to share this habit with the community.

Comment: Then you also could have a look at the internal `char[]`, which also can only contain only Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, as the size of an array is also given as `int`.

Comment: @amit - Can we create a String whose size > Integer.MAX_VALUE or will Java prevent us from doing that because of the int limit ? I tried it with a StringBuilder and got out of heap space error. I'll have to fix that first & then retry. Btw, my system has 16gb RAM and 60% is free.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing a single String of length 2 bn (This will use 8 GB of memory to create btw) You can create a collection of Strings.  Its not as easy to work with but can effectively be any length.

Comment: Can we create a String whose size > Integer.MAX_VALUE or will Java prevent us from doing that because of the int limit ?

Comment: @MasterJoe Jvms seems to have an array size limit of slightly less than 2^31-1 due to implementation details. Maybe this has been fixed but you cant get MAX_VALUE with Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Since String in java is a reference type, strings are stored in a contiguous block of memory. this block must be accessible by integer indices. The memory range must be between 0 and 2^32 -1  in a 32 bits computer architecture which is equal to int primitive data type range.

A basic integer data type can address your memory range. Therefore, you can not store any string which exceeds your memory.

In addition, you can not store any data which exceeds your program stack which is very limited range of memory compared to system memory. you will get stackOverFlow exception when the application memory is exceeded.